# Check if a Model will have children before they are created OR a property set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project and I'm trying to create a validation which checks if either conditions are met on creation

- a certain property is set
- it has at least one child of a certain has_many association

```
model = Model.new(property: nil)
model.save #not valid

model = Model.new(property: "value")
model.save #valid

model = Model.new
model.children.build
model.save #valid
```

The first two arent't a problem, as I can easily check if a property is set in a custom validation. What I'm having trouble with is the last one, as this won't work:

```
validate :has_data, on: :create

def has_data
  errors.add(:data, "isn't present") if property == nil && self.children.count == 0
end
```

It obviously hasn't gotten any children because these get created after the validation. There has to be a collection somewhere that is added to by association.build() that is read in save(), but by skimming through the Rails source I find my Ruby and Rails knowledge lacking in finding how to find this collection.

Is there any expert on this that may know how to retrieve this data or another way to make this validation possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that executing `self.children.count` will return the number of database records that exist, which is 0 because you haven't saved them yet. Try `size` instead:

```
def has_data
  errors.add(:data, "isn't present") if property.nil? && self.children.size == 0
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`model = Model.new
model.children.build
model.save`

I think the problem is at line 2, since you are trying to build a child before parent is saved, when your code is at line no 2, model's id would be `nil`, and to build child , child needs `parent_id` as foreign key. Also you need to save the child explicitly somewhat like this `model.children.build.save` unless you passed `autosave: true` in the model.

My recommendation to your problem would be like this

`model = Model.new
model.save.tap do |result|
result && model.children.build
end`

for the validation part you can do something like this, 
in your parent.rb

`validates_associated: :child, on: create, message: "isn't present" if property.nil?`

[reference link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated)